# How to disconnect session created by browser with Active Directory Server using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have an Intranet Website and when I does not log in from my Domain ID, browser automatically generate pop-up for Domain ID Username and Password.

Now the Problem is when I close my browser and some another user uses my Computer and opens the same browser, Browser will not again generate Pop-Up for Domain ID Username and Password and directly open the Intranet Website with my Domain ID.

Is there any way to terminate the session with AD Server when I Log-Out or close my browser.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you are closing all windows your application created?  any window created from the original window will share the same Session.

Comment: When I am Closing the Whole browser not that Particular Tab then it is working fine  but if I close the tab not the whole browser it should also disconnect the session but when I again trying to open the Portal on the same browser on another tab it is not asking again for Domain ID and Password.

Comment: @Rahul Browsers by default do not terminate sessions until the entire browser is closed.  The answer below uses JavaScript to handle this but you should never trust JavaScript to perform every action, specially when the page is being closed by the user.

Comment: @Brent If i check any of the bank Website and when I am Closing the Tab not the Whole Browser it is also Terminating my session and up to my Knowledge they are not using javascript for Security Reason and in case of Gmail you are right.

Comment: Can it be done making some changes in Machine.Config?

Comment: @Rahul Most bank sites terminate sessions after a period of inactivity or have other methods on the client (like the answer below) to kill a sessions when you leave.

Comment: When you log into a bank website, it does not use your active directory credentials, that is all windows authentication based. They are most likely using Form Authentication, which manages remote sessions. You can manage sessions better with the mentality that multiple users might be logging in from the same computer; not the same as windows authentication.

Comment: @sksallaj Yeah i know they use Form Authentication and here i am Using Windows Authentication...It was Just an Example..It has nothing to do Intranet Website...Thanks for your Support...:)

Comment: @Rahul, see my edited answer, you can't force Windows Authentication to work the same way as Form Authentication. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you....We can not work the same way we work with Form Authentication...but it was just an Example to tell them what i actually Want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory server does not have a way to manage client connections to the server. All it does is manage the user credentials and accessibility. To switch roles or users in the active directory, you'd literally have to log off of windows and go back on.

Here is a perfect article that explains how to capture an active directory user logging into your website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx

To replicate how YOU want users to log onto your site, your best bet is to go with Form Authentication, rather than using your Active Directory credentials. The mindset with Form Authentication is that you might have multiple users use the same computer logging into your website. Windows authentication has the mindset where only one user can log onto a computer so use that person's credentials by default to log onto the intranet website.

You can have the client send a request to disconnect from the server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx

You can also attempt to manage the User's session during log on as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah635ck5

the Abandon method seems to do the job that you'd want it to do.

Aside note: as a programmer using windows authentication, you don't have to worry about extra layers of security, but with Form authentication you have to keep security measures in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this applies to AD server but you can delete the session cookie when browser closes.

```
window.onunload=function()
{
   setCookie("YourCookieId","",-1);
}
```

Similarly on log-out you can set the expiration time to -1 years.

```
HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("YourCookieId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
```

Comment: Yes, I am talking about ASP.NET session, updated my answer to know use any cookie id.